# Selenium selecting link within table - with all the same name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Cant click on the link due to the fact, all of the value I keep trying to select has the same name as well within the tables.

Tried xpath,by link, by text, by css none of it works. My current code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="homeapp"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/a').click()
```

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<tr class="bui-table__row"><td class="peg-table__cell--no-label bui-table__cell" data-heading="ID" scope="row"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/index.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111" class="bui-link bui-link--secondary" target="_blank" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Property ID">
  1111(number i can click aswell)
</a></td> <td class="peg-table__cell--no-label bui-table__cell" data-heading="Name" scope="row"><div class="bui-avatar-block"><div class="peg-_-avatar-shrink bui-avatar"><img src="https://q-xx.bstatic.com/xdata/images/extra/square60/189090859.jpg?k=cc455d4d570f0e0c86a1b8329b16d53fdba96d78677cc87151d6181e45d38ec5&amp;o=" alt="text i want to click" class="bui-avatar__image"></div> <div class="bui-avatar-block__text"><span class="bui-avatar-block__title"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/index.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111" class="peg-property-link bui-link bui-link--secondary" target="_blank" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Property Name">
      Text i want to click 
      <!----> <!----></a></span> <span class="bui-avatar-block__subtitle"><!----> </span></div></div> <div class="bui-spacer--smaller"></div> <div class="peg-score-bar__inline bui-score-bar"><div class="bui-score-bar__item"><div class="bui-score-bar__header"><h2 class="bui-score-bar__title"></h2> <span class="bui-score-bar__score">93%</span></div> <div class="bui-score-bar__bar"><span data-value="9.3" class="bui-score-bar__value" style="width: 93%;"></span></div></div></div></td> <td class="peg-table__cell--no-label bui-table__cell" data-heading="Location"><div class="peg-address-wrapper"><span class="peg-flag-wrapper"><div class="peg-flag bui-flag"><img src="https://q.bstatic.com/backend_static/common/flags/16/nl/314ce6500532e846e25d6e3a7c824ef17c968446.png" class="bui-flag__flag" style="height: auto;"> <!----></div></span>
  TEXT2
</div></td> <td class="peg-table__cell--no-label bui-table__cell" data-heading="Status"><span>Open/Bookable</span></td> <td class="bui-table__cell bui-table__cell--center" data-heading="Arrivals/departures &amp; tomorrow"><span class="peg-counter--arrivals"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/search_reservations.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Arrivals" target="_blank" class="peg-counter peg-counter--has"><span aria-label="80 unread" class="bui-bubble">
  VALUE1
</span></a></span> <span class="peg-counter--departures"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/search_reservations.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111&amp;type=departure" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Departures" target="_blank" class="peg-counter peg-counter--has"><span aria-label="80 unread" class="bui-bubble">
  VALUE2
</span></a></span></td> <td class="bui-table__cell bui-table__cell--center" data-heading="Guest Messages"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/messaging_inbox.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Guest Messages" target="_blank" class="peg-counter peg-counter--has"><span aria-label="102 unread" class="bui-bubble">
  VALUE3
</span></a></td> <td class="bui-table__cell bui-table__cell--center" data-heading="extranet.com Messages"><a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/inbox.html?ses=8594ddf0718dec240a0c9e7991e108a8&amp;name_id=11111" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,extrabnet.com Messages" target="_blank" class="peg-counter"><span aria-label="0 unread" class="bui-bubble">
  0
</span></a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Not sure unless see the entire DOM.However check if this work. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="homeapp"]//table//tr//td[@data-heading="Name"]//a[contains(@data-track-ga,"Property Name")]').click()`

Comment: @Amptivity Instead of providing a handcrafted HTML update the question with text based actual HTML.

Comment: Its fully update now

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element, so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element to be clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "text i want to click"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.peg-property-link.bui-link.bui-link--secondary[href*='/extranet_ng/manage/index'][data-track-ga*='Active Properties']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='peg-property-link bui-link bui-link--secondary' and contains(@href, '/extranet_ng/manage/index')][starts-with(@data-track-ga, 'Groups')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, already tried the first one. It doesnt work. The other ones are based on the href url, but that one is dynamic see full link:
```
<a href="../../extranet_ng/manage/index.html?ses=99cc1a445a2b6c9423a2ff5c275e118b&amp;name_id=111111" class="peg-property-link bui-link bui-link--secondary" target="_blank" data-track-ga="Groups: Home,Active Properties,Property Name">
          Text i want to click
          <!----> <!----></a>
```

Comment: @Amptivity Instead of providing a handcrafted HTML update the question with text based actual HTML.

Comment: @Amptivity Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, its not working, i think its due the fact there's 3 <tr class="bui-table__row"> containing the same values. The only variable that changes are the text.

Comment: @Amptivity This isn't a comment but a well researched answer. _the fact there's 3 <tr class="bui-table__row">_ is exactly the reason I am asking for the relevant actual HTML

Comment: I was refering to your reply, not your method. The full HTML code is too large to fit in here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the link which contains `avatar` in its [class](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) attribute use the following XPath expression:

```
//div[contains(@class,'avatar')]/descendant::a[contains(text(), 'text i want to click')]
```

where:

- [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is [XPath Function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) allowing partial match on the attributes values and/or text
- [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) - XPath [Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) which matches children of the current node and their respective children
- last part limits the search to [hyperlinks](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) which contain text you're looking for

Comment: Not working, that's using a lot of variables that the other 3 tables contain. Get a error "Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "